# Long number Date Format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

In my application I return some data from controller in json format, and when this data come from controller my DateTime field has next format: `"/Date(1366146000000)/"`
In controller this field before sending has format: `{4/17/2013 12:00:00 AM}`

Kendo Ui datepicker display that date good, but when I want to update some object and I don't want to update field with that date, there are some problems with parsing.

When I change date in `kendo ui datepicker`, date format changing also, but if I don't change it still has that long format.
Maybe there is some solution that prevent returning in this format, or returning that date `("/Date(1366146000000)/")` from kendo ui datePicker in another format, for example something like this: `"Wed Apr 17 00:00:00 UTC+0300 2013"`.

Comment: Sorry but what is your problem? Is it that the date from the datepicker is not in the right format when you do a POST? Or is it that you cannot get the right format when you extract the value from the datepicker in javascript?

Comment: How I can parse 13 digit number: "1366146000000"
to format: "Wed Apr 17 00:00:00 UTC+0300 2013" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** This may not be the best answer but this works for me.

> How I can parse 13 digit number: "1366146000000" to format: "Wed Apr
>   17 00:00:00 UTC+0300 2013" ?

You will need to use jquery UI in my proposed solution. I've gotten this somewhere and I forgot where so I cannot give the proper credit to that person. Anyway, here's that code on which I made a tiny improvement:

```
function getProperDate(date) {
    if (date == null) return null;
    return new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
}
function getFormattedDate(dt, format) {
    return $.datepicker.formatDate(
        (format==null || format=='' ? 'M dd, yy' : format), 
        getProperDate(dt));
}
```

You can then pass `1366146000000`, which is expected to be a valid date value, to `getProperDate`.

Comment: thanks, it works too, but I find solution in kendo ui with method parseDate

date = kendo.parseDate(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");